# one Section 100% high of viewport, then another section visible when scroll down

Tags: css

I'm trying to find out how this website was styled (http://hairproject.ch/fr/).
I like the idea when you open it, header image is cover 100% of viewport, no matter what browser size is. But then you can scroll down to another section.

I'm trying to recreate that CSS, an I end up having this:

```
header {            
    display: block;         
    background-image: url(background_03.jpg);           
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;         
    background-size: cover;         
    height: 100%;           
    width: 100%;            
    position: absolute;         
    left: 0;            
    top: 0;
}
```

This makes image cover whole viewport, but absolute positioning takes that header out from normal workflow and put other section underneath.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe parent element of the header has a fixed height (currently 402px on my screen) and relative positioning. This is what causes the content to drop below the header.

```
<div id="banner" style="height:402px;">
```

The site is using JS to keep this height correct.

Script source: http://static.hairproject.ch/js/script.js

Code of interest:

```
// Figure out browser width/height and ajust main picture -------------------------------------------------
var width  = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
if ((width > 320) && (width <= 480)) { height = height + 240; }
else if (width <= 320) { height = height + 80; }
var margintop = Math.round((height/3) - 120);
$("body.home #banner").attr("style","height:" + height + "px;");
$("body.home h2").attr("style","margin-top:" + margintop + "px");

$(window).resize(function() {
  // $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>');
  var width  = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  if ((width > 320) && (width <= 480)) { height = height + 240; }
  else if (width <= 320) { height = height + 80; }
  var margintop = Math.round((height/3) - 120);
  $("body.home #banner").attr("style","height:" + height + "px;");
  $("body.home h2").attr("style","margin-top:" + margintop + "px");
});
```

Comment: I knew there must be some JavaSrcipt. Thanks flem!